# Where to put bank info for Apple In App Purchases on Free App

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have setup IAP on Unity and have built the project to IOS but it doesn't seem to pop up. I have run the same thing on Android and it works fine so the error has nothing to do with the code, and I am pretty sure I have set up everything correctly on App Store.

I came across this person who seemed to be having a similar problem to me:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1273037/unity-iap-not-working-on-ios-works-on-android.html

and it makes sense because I haven't input any bank info into ITunesConnect, but I can't seem to figure out where to put this bank account info. I went into Agreements, Taxes, and Banking, but all I see is a Free Applications Contract that says N/A in Bank Info section and a Paid Applications Contract that I can request and has a Bank Info section that can be editted.

My application is not paid and I'm not sure where else to put my bank info.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to below link. You need to fill **paid app contract and banking information** for in-app purchases.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/Introduction.html

To configure in-app purchase content in iTunes Connect, you need access to:

- The latest Apple Developer Program License Agreement See Legal
  Agreements in your account at develop.apple.com.
- **The latest paid app contract Open the Agreements, Tax, and Banking
  module in iTunes Connect, as described in Managing Agreements, Tax,
  and Banking in iTunes Connect Developer Guide.**
- An iTunes Connect user account with an appropriate role See Setting
  Up User Accounts in iTunes Connect Developer Guide.
- An iTunes Connect record for your app See Creating an iTunes Connect
  Record for an App in iTunes Connect Developer Guide.

Comment: Thnx. I assumed that since my app wasn't paid I wouldn't have to use the paid app contract, but one of my friends that developed for apple said this as well, so I guess I'll go ahead and set it up like this.